# Is stack overflow for API based applications only?

Tags: android

Does stack overflow support VPS/dedicated server with Postgres-XL +mongo combination and remote database server service?

Comment: Stack overflow doesn't support anything.  Its a place developers can ask other developers questions.  If your question is about programming or programming tools (IDEs, debuggers, etc), it can be asked here.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to ask is parse.com for API applications only or does parse.com support VPS/dedicated server with Postgres-XL +mongo combination and remote database server service?